# permission denied on Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, permission-denied

I have got a problem deploying my app on Passenger through Capistrano.

I can't seem to shake off a Permission denied - /path/to/app/Gemfile.lock from bundler/definition.rb. Has anyone had this before?

I have tried chmoding and chowning the file but that hasn't helped.

Has anybody else had the problem?

Back trace is

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb 184 in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb 184 in `open'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb 184 in `lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/environment.rb 39 in `lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 35 in `setup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb 100 in `setup'
```

**UPDATE:** After viewing the following link - [here](http://bit.ly/gDHjjj), I managed to fix the issue by bundling on dev and then recommiting the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Facing exactly the same exception . Did you manage to shake the error off ?

Comment: try re-running bundle install locally and recommit your Gemfile.lock before deploying again.  worked for me

Comment: I upgraded the bundler version in the server and the error disappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try deleting the Gemfile.lock and running `bundle install` on your server.

Comment: Hi Kevin,  I have tried that but no joy unfortunately.  What user/group does Passenger access files from?  I am ssh'ed in as root.  Could it be anything to do with that?

Comment: To answer the question, from the docs: "A Rails application is started as the owner of the file `config/environment.rb`, and a Rack application is started as the owner of the file `config.ru`. So if `/home/webapps/foo/config/environment.rb` is owned by `joe`, then Phusion Passenger will launch the corresponding Rails application as `joe` as well."

Comment: Worked like a charm, im also running passenger

Answer (score 1):

It's worth checking the owner of the lock file. Ran into this when I'd been running 'sudo bundle install' because I'd been installing the gemfiles for all users on the box. A quick 'chown' later, and everything was sorted.